# Vagrant Synced Folders not showing

Tags: macos, vagrant

I want to sync my OSX dev folder which contains my applications to my VM. My VagrantFile (based off Phansible):

```
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.5"
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
        v.name = "default"
        v.customize [
            "modifyvm", :id,
            "--name", "default",
            "--memory", 512,
            "--natdnshostresolver1", "on",
            "--cpus", 1,
        ]
    end

    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"        
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.99"
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true

    if which('ansible-playbook')
        config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
            ansible.playbook = "ansible/playbook.yml"
            ansible.inventory_path = "ansible/inventories/dev"
            ansible.limit = 'all'
            ansible.extra_vars = {
                private_interface: "192.168.33.99",
                hostname: "default"
            }
        end
    else
        config.vm.provision :shell, path: "ansible/windows.sh", args: ["default"]
    end

    config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/xylar/Code", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
end
```

When I `vagrant up`:

```
==> default: Exporting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible...
```

There are no error messages and when I `vagrant ssh` and view contents of the vagrant folder I only see some dot files (ansible, bash etc). Is there something I have missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was being foolish. Once I had ssh'd into the box I thought I was in the synced folder (as it was called vagrant) however I was in `/home/vagrant` and the synced location was in `/vagrant`.

Comment: Wow I've been trying to figure out my homework for 4 hours. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the mount options:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/xylar/Code", "/vagrant", "nfs" => { :mount_options => ['dmode=777', 'fmode=777'] }
```